# Display message (or empty graph) when empty dataset is added

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I'm adding an onChange() handler to the crossfilter associated with my dc.js graph.  One of the changes I'm looking for is the 'dataAdded' event.  When I add a data set with >= 1 record, the graph renders properly and I see that onChange() callback gets triggered with the 'dataAdded' event.  If I add a data set with 0 records then the graph does not render properly and the onChange() callback is never triggered.  I would have thought that since I'm supplying an empty array to the crossfilter then it would trigger the 'dataAdded' event but evidently it does not.  This makes some measure of sense, but still.

The main issue that I'm experiencing is that when the data set is empty then nothing is rendered.  The graph doesn't render as it normally would (e.g., axis names, empty pie/donut/row/bar, etc) to give any indication that something happened.

What I was **hoping** to do was add a test as part of the 'dataAdded' event in order to see if the data set was empty.  If it was then somehow let the user know that a request to the server was made but nothing came back.  Is there a way to do this a different way?  Is there a way where I can force the graph to render as empty?  Make it so that the graph displays a custom message?

I've been digging around but haven't really been able to find out much information about this particular case.

thnx,
Christoph

Comment: Hmm, no `dataAdded` event if the data is an empty array, okay... I guess you will have to detect it yourself for now. It would be nice to have a built-in dc.js feature to show a message when there is no data. For now, [here is the feature request](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1242) with some example code that works for many of the charts.